# MATLAB: wild cards in vectors (E.g. [1,2,3,*,*,*,*])

Tags: matlab, octave

Simple enough question, but I'm not finding a simple solution:

I want to say, "is this vector 1, 4, 7, and then 5 of whatever number?"

For example:

```
[1,4,7,2,6,5,8,3]
```

...or:

```
[1,4,7,2,8,5,9,2]
```

The final five numbers can be anything, as long as they're numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that MATLAB should pick the numbers (then call `rand()`) or draw them from some existing data (e.g. they become don't-care in some comparison, by becoming equal to whatever is the corresponding element in the other vector) ?  For the latter, instead of filling a vector with wildcards, you should just select only the portions of the other vector that you want to match.

Comment: No, I apologize for not explaining clearly. Basically, I want to test that a vector of 9 numbers starts with "1,4,7". After that, what order the numbers are in doesn't matter to me.

Comment: then use `v(1:3) == [1 4 7]`.  Like I said, select the portions you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Subscript can itself be another vector in Matlab. So you can test any values in vector:

```
x=zeros(1,10);
x(1)=1;x(2)=2; x(3)=3;x(6)=4;x(9)=5;
x                 % x =   1   2   3   0   0   4   0   0   5   0
L=[1:3,6,9];      %subscipt of vector v
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
isequal(x(L),y)   % ans = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test these two conditions separately and then combine them with `and`.

```
x1 = [1,4,7,2,6,5,8,3];
is147 = all(x1(1:3)==[1,4,7]);
and(is147,length(x1)==8)
```

I think, for a list, the last 5 numbers have to be numeric, but if not you can put in extra tests, such as `isnumeric()`. Also if the input changes between column and row vectors, you can force a row vector with `x_col = x1(:)`

Comment: Basically what @SergV said

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will check if your variable is a vector, [`isvector`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvector.html), verify it has a length of 8 and check that the first 3 elements are [1 4 7], [`isequal`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/isequal.html).

```
>> v = [1 4 7 2 6 5 8 3];
>> isvector(v) && numel(v) == 8 && isequal(v(1:3), [1 4 7])
ans =

     1

>> v = [1 4 7 2 6 5 8];
>> isvector(v) && numel(v) == 8 && isequal(v(1:3), [1 4 7])
ans =

     0

>> v = [9 4 7 2 6 5 8 3];
>> isvector(v) && numel(v) == 8 && isequal(v(1:3), [1 4 7])
ans =

     0

>> v = [1 4 7 2; 6 5 8 3];
>> isvector(v) && numel(v) == 8 && isequal(v(1:3), [1 4 7])
ans =

     0
```